# Python dictionary or map in elisp

Tags: elisp, emacs24

What is the equivalent of a python dictionary like `{'a':1, 'b':2}` in elisp?
And again, does elisp have any map-reduce api?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Association lists](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Association-Lists.html#Association-Lists) are the most commonly used associative containers in elisp. It is just a list of key-value cons cells like this `((key . value))`. You can use the `assoc` function to get a value corresponding to a key and `rassoc` to get a key with the required value.

Elisp comes with the built-in function [`mapcar`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mapping-Functions.html) which does map, but AFAIK there is no good `fold` facility. You could emulate it using any of the looping facilities provided. However, the better solution is to use `cl-lib` and slip into CommonLisp land. In particular, [it supplies](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Mapping-over-Sequences.html#Mapping-over-Sequences) `cl-mapcar` and `cl-reduce`.

Comment: pradhan, to get value from a map, can one use assq (or) assoc?

Comment: Usually, `assoc` is what makes sense because that compares the keys with `equal`. On the other hand, `assq` compares with `eq` which requires that they be the exact same object in memory.

Answer (score 8):

Besides association lists,(whose algorithmic complexity is OK for small tables but not for large ones), there are hash tables, you can construct with `make-hash-table` and `puthash`, or if you prefer immediate values, you can write them as `#s(hash-table data a 1 b 2)`.