# elisp how can i input a hashmap directly? how did Hash's read-syntax like?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to input a hash directly like javascript:

```
hash = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2',
  key3: 'value3'
}
```

For this improving readability sometimes,

I tried this in elisp:

```
 #s(:a 1 :b 2)
```

but take an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python dictionary or map in elisp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664267/python-dictionary-or-map-in-elisp)

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can do it like this, and it works.

```
 #s(hash-table data (
   :key1   "value1"
   :key2   "value2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

from http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_hash_table.html:

```
(setq myHash
  #s(hash-table
     size 30
     test equal
     data (
           "joe" 3
           "jane" 9
           "liz" 5 )))



;; test
(gethash "joe" myHash ) ; 3
```

Quote: The :test 'equal is to specify what function to use to test key existence.

I haven't seen about size, but assume it is the maximum size, I tried it without and it worked for me (I just needed it static).